# A measure has no point masses: is it absolutely continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I have a question about measure theory.

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Assume that $\mu$ has no point masses - i.e. for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu({a})=0$. Can we say that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure? In other words, does $\mu$ admit a density?

That is the question. Just to provide some background, I'm working on deriving some concentration inequalities involving the random variable: $\int_0^1 B_s^4 ds$ where $(B_s, s \in [0,1])$ is a fractional Brownian motion. I need to show that the random variable $\int_0^1 B_s^4 ds$ has a density to apply some results. I can show that the measure induced on $\mathbb{R}$ by this random variable has not point masses, and I want to conclude that it has a density.

Thank you!!

John

Comment: Cantor distribution has no point masses but does not admit a density.

Comment: No, not at all.  For the measure to admit a density, its cumulative distribution function must be differentiable a.e.  On the other hand, for the measure to have no point masses, it suffices that the cumulative distribution function is continuous (and non-decreasing).  There are plenty of non-decreasing functions that are continuous but nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Thank you, that settles my question! :)
(Thanks both for the counterexample and the explanation).